# How to iterate over YAML config and get options?

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, yaml, config

I have this YAML config file:

```
sheets:
  list1:
    name: 'sheet1'
    sql: 'SELECT'
  list2:
    name: 'sheet2'
    sql: 'SELECT'
  list3:
    name: 'sheet3'
    sql: 'SELECT'
```

I use library `'js-yaml'` for parsing YAML config.
I want to for example console log all list names. How can I do this? I have something like this in JS:

```
for(sheet in config.sheets) {
    console.log(sheet.name);
}
```

when I do `console.log(sheet)` in loop i get list1, list2, list3 but `console.log(sheet.name)` in loop doesn't work.

Comment: Probably depends on what library you're using to parse the YAML. The quickest way to solve a problem when you don't have "too much time" is to search the web and see how other people have solved it rather than wait for an answer here. This is a solved problem.

Comment: Yes I do both....googling and questioning. But don't have time for configs so I can do something else somewhile someone maybe helps me there.  Library I use is 'js-yaml'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--if you're using js-yaml, which converts a config file to an object, what's the specific problem? Even if it wasn't clear, just dumping the parsed document would surely provide some idea of what to do with the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a tool like [js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml) , to first convert your `yaml` to a `js literal`.

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
let data = yaml.load(config);
```

It will return the data like this:

```
 {
       sheets: {
          list1: {
           name: "sheet1",
           sql: 'SELECT'
        },
......other lists
     }
   }
```

then you can simply

```
const data = {
  sheets: {
    list1: {
      name: "sheet1",
      sql: 'SELECT'
    },
    list2: {
      name: "sheet2",
      sql: 'SELECT'
    }
  }
}

const name = Object.values(data.sheets).map(item => item.name)
console.log(values);
```